# The meaning of "a" in an awk command?

Tags: awk

I have an awk command in a script I am trying to make work, and I don't understand the meaning of 'a':

> awk 'FNR==NR{ a[$1]=$0;next } ($2 in a)' FILELIST.TXT FILEIN.* > FILEOUT.*

I'm quite new to using command line, so I'm just trying to figure things out, thanks.

Comment: It is an array. See http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ for further reference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a` is an associative array.

```
a[$1] = $0;
```

takes the first word `$1` on the line as the index in the array, and stores the whole line `$0` as the value.  It does this for the first file (while the file record number is equal to the overall record number).  The `next` command means it doesn't process the rest of the script while it is processing the first file.

For the rest of the data files, it evaluates:

```
($2 in a)
```

and prints the line if the word in `$2` is found.  This makes storing `$0` in `a` relatively expensive because it is storing a copy of the whole file (possibly twice if there's only one word on each line of the file).  It is more conventional and sufficient to do `a[$1]++` or even `a[$1] = 1`.

Given FILELIST.TXT

```
ABC The rest
DEF And more
```

Given FILEIN.1 containing:

```
Word ABC and so on
Grow FED won't be shown
This DEF will be shown
The XYZ will be missing
```

The output will be:

```
Word ABC and so on
This DEF will be shown
```

Answer (score 3):

Here `a` is not a command but an `awk array` it can very well be `arr` also:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {arr[$1]=$0;next} ($2 in arr)' FILELIST.TXT FILEIN.* > FILEOUT.*
```

Answer (score 2):

a is nothing but an array, in your code

```
FNR==NR{ a[$1]=$0;next }
```

Creates an array called "a" with indexes taken from the first column of the first input file. 
All element values are set to the current record.

The next statement forces awk to immediately stop processing the current record and go on to the next record.